# AWS Glue enableUpdateCatalog not creating new partitions after successful job run

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am having a problem, where i have set `enableUpdateCatalog=True` and also `updateBehaviour=LOG` to update my glue table which has 1 partition key. After the job, runs there are no new partitions added on my glue catalog table, but data in S3 is separated by the partition key i have used, how do i get the job to *automatically* partition my glue catalog table?
Currently i have to manually run boto3 `create_partition` to create partitions on my glue catalog table. I want my job to automatically be able to create partitions as it discovers in S3 path separated by partition Keys
Code:

```
additionalOptions = {
    "enableUpdateCatalog": True, 
    "updateBehavior": "LOG"}
additionalOptions["partitionKeys"] = ["partition_key0", "partition_key1"]

my_df = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_catalog(frame=last_transform, database=<dst_db_name>,
    table_name=<dst_tbl_name>, transformation_ctx="DataSink1",
    additional_options=additionalOptions)
job.commit()
```

PS: I am currently using **PARQUET** format

Am i missing any Rights that has to be added to my job so that it can create partitions from the job itself?

Comment: can you provide some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by adding useGlueParquetWriter: 'true' to the CATALOG table properties. And also I have added

```
format_options = {
'useGlueParquetWriter': True
}
```

in the `write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog` calls.
These steps got it to start working :)